# list comprehension for dictionary values, assigning 0 or 1 based on value

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to use a list comprehension to create a vector of 0s and 1s based on values in a dictionary.

In this example, I want every positive number to be returned as 1 and every 0 number to remain 0. However, I need the solution changeable such that if I wanted to set the threshold to 0.25 (instead of 0) I could easily make that change.

```py
test_dict = {'a':0.6, 'b':0, 'c':1, 'd':0.5}
skill_vector = [1 for skill.values() in test_dict if skill.values > 0 else 0]
```

Desired output:
[1,0,1,1]

Edit: As wiser minds have pointed out, dictionary are not ordered so the output would not be of use. In light of this, I intend to make use of the OrderedDict subclass.

Comment: this sounds like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You cannot trust the order of elements `values()` returns in the general case, so I am not sure what this list could be useful for..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cast the boolean from your test to an int rather than using the `if/else` pattern:

```
test_dict = {'a':0.6, 'b':0, 'c':1, 'd':0.5}

threshold = 0
[int(v > threshold) for v in test_dict.values()]
# [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

This assumes you're using a version of python that keeps the keys in insert order.

Comment: Does the int function apply some rounding? I'm sure that it is; I just never would have thought of this approach.

Comment: @mjake `v > threshold` is just a Boolean — True of False. `int()` just turns them into 1 or zero. It doesn't need to really round sine `True == 1` already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test_dict = {'a':0.6, 'b':0, 'c':1, 'd':0.5}
>>> [1 if x > 0 else 0 for x in test_dict.values()]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
```

You can also use a dictionary comprehension to ensure the result is mapped to the correct key:

```
>>> {k:1 if v > 0 else 0 for k,v in test_dict.items()}
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the skill_values function:

```
def skill_values(x):
     return skill_values >= .25

skill_vector = [1 if skill_values(x) else 0 for x in test_dict.values()]
```

or incorporating the mapping to int from another answer

```
skill_vector = [int(skill_values(x)) for x in test_dict.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
test_dict = {'a':0.6, 'b':0, 'c':1, 'd':0.5}
skill_vector = list(map(int, map(bool, test_dict.values())))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 0, 1, 1]
```